# ios 15 showing incorrect storage

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, storage, mobile-device-management

I just had a look at the storage consumption in my phone and it seems to be incorrect. It shows that the phone has consumed only ~4 GB from my 32GB. I think that's wrong because up until I updated the phone to iOS 15, I’ve for most of the time since last year been at the brink of my storage limit (notification for storage almost full always on my face).

After updating to 15. The notification is missing…

Besides the totals didn't add up… Photos + Apps taking more than 4GB and System Software ~7GB.

A few days back I even updated it to 15.0.1. (I’m not sure but I thought there was a storage fix in this). Didn't see any more new updates after that as of this writing.

Model: iPhone 7 plus (32GB)
iOS version: 15.0.1

This is a bit concerning, if storage is full the phone would just keep crashing if it's not indicating correctly right?

Is this a bug? Or some optimizations in storage management…(I can't imagine this level of it though)